# Infix to postfix problem with unary operators

Tags: data-structures, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation, shunting-yard

I use the following logic to implement an infix to postfix conversion, to evaluate it later.

- The loop on the infix conversion, and in each iteration, do the following:

  - If space, ignore it.
  - If operator, then keeps popping from the stack and add to the postfix output until the stack is empty or the top of the stack has a lower priority than the current operator. Then, push the current operator.
  - If '(', push it.
  - If '), keep popping and adding to the postfix until you find '('. Then pop the '(' without adding it.
  - Otherwise, then it's a number. Add it directly to the postfix output.

Notes: When I encounter a `+` or `-`, I can determine whether it's a binary or unary operator. If it's binary I add it to the stack as '+' or `-`, but if it's unary I add it as '@' or '$'.

The algorithm works well, except in a case where two unary operators are next to each other.

For example, `"--4"` becomes `"@ 4 @"`, which is wrong.

What's wrong? What's the correct fix to this issue, that doesn't break other cases?

Comment: What you describe sounds like the correct solution. Without looking at your code, it's impossible to say where you went wrong.

Comment: @JimMischel It doesn't need code. Following the algorithm by hand generates "@ 4 @" for "--4"

Comment: @JimMischel Let me explain by steps:
At first I'll find `-` that is unary operator, so I'll push it.
Then, I'll find another `-` that is also a unary operator, I'll pop the '@' and add it to the output.
Then, I'll find `4` and add it to the output, then add the only one item in the stack to the output.
Following the algorithm by hand leads to wrong answer "@ 4 @"
The correct should be "4 @ @". What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to change your rules so that you don't pop for successive unary operators. That is, given "--4":

1. You identify the `-` as a unary operator, and push `@`
2. You identify the next `-` as a unary operator, see that the operator on the stack is also a unary operator, and push another `@`.
3. You see the `4`, and output it.
4. At the end of the string, you pop the two unary operators, giving you "4@@".

And of course the unary operators should have higher precedence than any other operator, so that they'll always get popped before any other operator is pushed.